# How to parse a necessary object from html code using find_all beautilullsoup

Tags: python, html, parsing

I write parsing code using python and i meet with trouble:
i don't know how to get necessary object from with page (https://buff.163.com/market/csgo#tab=selling&page_num=1)
F.e. i wanna get price of skin whose name is 'StatTrak™ MAG-7 | Cobalt Core (Well-Worn)':
[image]
[image]I see a lot of obeject with tag and the first of them is what I need
How can I get this object and his price?

I use this code for this aim:

```
url = 'https://buff.163.com/market/csgo#tab=selling&page_num=1'
main_url='https://buff.163.com/'
request = requests.get(url)
req = request.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'lxml')
li = soup.find_all('li')
li
```

but i dont understand how i can find right tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see in the browser is loaded from external source using JavaScript. You can use this example how to get the items data:

```py
import requests

url = "https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods"
params = {"game": "csgo", "page_num": "1", "use_suggestion": "0"}

data = requests.get(url, params=params, cookies={"Locale-Supported": "en"}).json()
for i in data["data"]["items"]:
    print(f'{i["name"]:<50} {i["quick_price"]}')
```

Prints:

```
Nova | Windblown (Factory New)                     2.12
★ Gut Knife | Bright Water (Minimal Wear)          664.5
MAC-10 | Red Filigree (Factory New)                563.5
★ Karambit | Stained (Battle-Scarred)              3285.5
Dual Berettas | Tread (Minimal Wear)               3.65
Souvenir USP-S | Desert Tactical (Well-Worn)       3.73
SSG 08 | Azure Glyph (Factory New)                 4.19
Souvenir CZ75-Auto | Silver (Factory New)          3.96
StatTrak™ Tec-9 | Brother (Well-Worn)              3.67
Souvenir PP-Bizon | Carbon Fiber (Factory New)     3.83
Souvenir PP-Bizon | Facility Sketch (Minimal Wear) 3.9
XM1014 | Teclu Burner (Battle-Scarred)             4.06
SSG 08 | Necropos (Minimal Wear)                   3.98
MP9 | Goo (Minimal Wear)                           3.78
StatTrak™ P2000 | Wicked Sick (Field-Tested)       31.41
AWP | POP AWP (Minimal Wear)                       24.7
StatTrak™ AWP | Exoskeleton (Battle-Scarred)       27.02
XM1014 | Entombed (Minimal Wear)                   25.13
AK-47 | Baroque Purple (Minimal Wear)              29.89
StatTrak™ Nova | Wild Six (Minimal Wear)           7.69
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works
But can you explain, how you understand that right way to extract data use 'https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods' link, not 'https://buff.163.com/market/csgo#tab=selling&page_num=1' ?
If I go to the site and follow the link "market" I see the site, url which 'https://buff.163.com/market/csgotab=selling&page_num=1', not your link
Thanks for your time!

Comment: @ArtemGorbunov When you open Web Developer Tools in your browser and switch to the Network tab, reload the page -  you shall see the API URL there.